# Firing Events/Loading Data upon Windows Form initialization (MVC)

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Okay, so I have a basic MVC setup for my windows form application.  What I am trying to do upon starting the application is launch a splash screen on a separate thread, while the splash screen is showing, fire an event to have the controller load in my static database from the model, and upon completion of that to close the splash and launch the primary form.

However, I have come to learn that you cant manually invoke events from the constructor.... does anyone have a workaround for this?

Here is my splash form

```
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
    {
        //Delegate for cross thread call to close
        private delegate void CloseDelegate();

        //The type of form to be displayed as the splash screen
        static SplashScreen splashScreen = null;

        public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // A static entry point to launch SplashScreen.
        static private void ShowForm()
        {
            splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
            Application.Run(splashScreen);
        }

        static public void ShowSplashScreen()
        {
            // Make sure it is only launched once.
            if (splashScreen != null)
                return;
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashScreen.ShowForm));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }

        // A static method to close the SplashScreen
        static public void CloseForm()
        {
            if (splashScreen != null)
            {
                splashScreen.Invoke(new CloseDelegate(SplashScreen.CloseFormInternal));
            }
        }

        static private void CloseFormInternal()
        {
            splashScreen.Close();
            splashScreen = null;
        }
    }
```

Here is what I am doing in my main form

```
public partial class Map : Form, IMapView
    {

        // Dictionary to hold overlays
        private static List<GMapOverlay> overlays = new List<GMapOverlay>();

        // global variables to track status of buttons
        private bool closedButtonStatus;
        private bool titleButtonStatus;

        /// <summary>
        /// Fired upon starting application
        /// </summary>
        public event Action StartupEvent;


        /// <summary>
        /// view constructor
        /// Creates a new real estate data map and loads in the county boundary data
        /// </summary>
        public Map()
        {
            SplashScreen.ShowSplashScreen();
            StartupEvent?.Invoke();
            SplashScreen.CloseForm();
            closedButtonStatus = false;
            titleButtonStatus = false;
            InitializeComponent();
            loadMap();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the map and centers it over the united states, with desired default size metrics
        /// </summary>
        private void loadMap()
        {

            // Initialize map:
            gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
            GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;

            // Center map over the US
            gmap.Position = new PointLatLng(40, -98);
            this.Size = new Size(1360, 665);
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(1000, 600);
        }
```

So the event I'm trying to invoke is "StartupEvent" in the Map constructor, however, it won't fire.

Comment: But at the time of the Map constructor, nothing has subscribed to the event yet so StartupEvent is null. Thus nothing to invoke.

Comment: right, that's what I've come to realize. Do you know an alternate way I can invoke an event or at least a method to the control?

Comment: That's just it though, there is nothing to invoke if no one has subscribed to the event. What exactly are you trying to do while the splash screen is displayed? If there is a method to call then call it at that time.

Comment: I'm trying to call a method in my controller class that has the model load in the massive dataset. I just don't know how to call methods in the controller class without even listeners

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set your primary forms opacity property to 0%.

When you launch your program the primary form will launch but not be visible.

You can then display your splash screen from a primary form event, something like the 'Load' event. You can also launch your database load, etc.

Once you have achieved whatever startup processing you require you can shutdown your splash screen form and set the opacity of your primary form to 100%, which will cause it to become visible.